# Windows prints everything too light

Tags: windows-10, printing, printer

So every time I print something using Window's software, such as Paint and the photo printing stuff, everything is printed in a light tone. I'd say it's about 25% lighter than it should be. When I print with GIMP, Photoscape, Photoshop, Illustrator, etc everything prints correctly!

This is very annoying and I have to open everything with another program just to print right. What could possibly cause this?

- Printer: Canon MP250
- OS: Windows 10

Comment: Look in the printer properties of your printer for settings such as "draft mode," "ink saver," etc. and try disabling any you find.

Comment: That wouldn't make sense since it works fine in other programs. The Windows printer properties are set up correct too, trust me I've been dealing with this for months.

Comment: If the settings are correct, then so be it. However, it's possible for programs to override these settings, which would provide an explanation why more advanced programs print correctly while those that just send basic printouts to the print queue would be adversely affected by said settings.

Comment: You can also try creating a *second* print queue for the printer and see if the problem persists when using it.

Comment: Have you checked all apps are using the same profiles?

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't even understand the whole profile thing. I mean, I know they are the preset settings and stuff, but they have unobvious names that make no sense to me.

Comment: Every device comes with a default manufacturer's profile. Assuming they are all somewhere close to your specific device [& sometimes they can be miles out] & also that your colour workflow has been correctly set up, then all apps should produce the same colours. The only way to absolutely ensure the profiles are correct is to buy a hardware colorimeter, then learn how to match your profiles right through your workflow. It's not a simple subject & it's way off-topic for SU, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation at least, do you have any other suggestions for my situation?

Comment: Short of manually compensating each & every time, no, sorry. There's nothing to replace a calibrated workflow.